# Converting zip codes into cities in pandas column using .replace()

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a column of zipcodes that I'm trying to convert to cities by using the uszipcode module. My Dataframe:

```
index   Color   Postal_Code
0       blue    10006.0 
1       green   11415.0
2       red     10037.0
```

I wrote this code and use .replace() to update the column:

```
def zco():
    for x in zcode['Postal_Code']:
        x = int(x)                          #convert to int because value is float
        city = search.by_zipcode(x)['City'] #Module extracts the city name 
        if city == str(city):               #The module doesn't recognize some zipcodes, thus generating None.This will skip None values.
            str(x).replace(str(x), city)    #replace int value with city
        else: continue

zcode['Postal_Code'] = zcode['Postal_Code'].apply(zco())
```

But I get an error:

> 'NoneType' object is not callable

**Why is that? Is there a better way to replace and update the postal codes in the column?**

Comment: There are some NaN values in `Postal_Code` column. Is it OK?

Comment: Yes, there are some Nan values in the column. I'm not sure if my code would work with that. I didn't address that yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main issue is that you are not passing a proper callable to `df.apply`, rather you are calling `zco()` which returns `None`, and passing *that* to apply.

In addition, `zco` must be a callable capable of taking a single argument, not iterating over the entire column at once. `df.apply` already takes care of this.

You can do the conversion of zip codes a bit quicker outside `zco` using `df.astype`:

```
 zcode['Postal_Code'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str).apply(zco)
```

And subsequently your `zco` definition can be shortened to:

```
def zco(x):
    city = search.by_zipcode(x)['City']  
    return city if city else x  # if city is None for certain zipcodes, take advantage of the truthiness of None
```

Note that `zco`'s definition has changed significantly, to accept an argument and operate only on one item at a time, not the entire row.

Alternatively, you could also use `df.transform(callable, axis=1)`:

```
zcode['Postal_Code'].fillna(0).astype(int).astype(str).transform(zco)
```

Comment: Thank you @COLDSPEED. The only change I have to make is take jezrael's suggestion and convert the x value inside the function after checking for Na values, because with the above solution I get an error: cannot convert Na to integer. Thank you for your detailed comments. It helped me understand how to use the def function with apply better.

Comment: @AdamSchroeder Okay, I have amended that in my answer. Position `df.fillna` before the conversion is to be done. Also remember that you can accept an answer if it helped. Thanks. :)

Comment: thank you @coldspeed Can you please explain to me why you used .transform(zco, axis=1). What does that do?

Comment: @AdamSchroeder `df.transform` is a new addition to the API since 0.18 (I think), and axis=1 is actually not needed. Will remove.

Answer (score 1):

I think problem is some `None` or `NaN` values, so is necessary add one `if` in function. There is also problem cannot cast `NaN` to `int`.

```
from uszipcode import ZipcodeSearchEngine
search = ZipcodeSearchEngine()

zcode = pd.DataFrame({'Postal_Code':[10006.0, 11415, 10037, 10, np.nan]})
print (zcode)
   Postal_Code
0      10006.0
1      11415.0
2      10037.0
3         10.0
4          NaN

def zco(x):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return None
    else:
        city = search.by_zipcode(int(x))['City']
        return city if city else x

zcode['City'] = zcode['Postal_Code'].apply(zco)
print (zcode)

   Postal_Code         City
0      10006.0     New York
1      11415.0  Kew Gardens
2      10037.0     New York
3         10.0           10
4          NaN         None
```

Or if need `None` for missing codes:

```
def zco(x):
    if pd.isnull(x):
        return None
    else:
        city = search.by_zipcode(int(x))['City']
        return city

zcode['City'] = zcode['Postal_Code'].apply(zco)
print (zcode)
   Postal_Code         City
0      10006.0     New York
1      11415.0  Kew Gardens
2      10037.0     New York
3         10.0         None
4          NaN         None
```

Also solution can be simplify:

```
def zco(x):
    return search.by_zipcode(x)['City']

zcode['City'] = zcode['Postal_Code'].fillna(0).astype(int).apply(zco)
print (zcode)
   Postal_Code         City
0      10006.0     New York
1      11415.0  Kew Gardens
2      10037.0     New York
3         10.0         None
4          NaN         None
```

Comment: Thank you for catching the Nan values, @jezrael and offering a solution before I even understood this would be a problem :)

Comment: Yes, main problem was install library. But I understand, cannot accept both solutions. Good luck!